# MySQL spatial relation query returning empty result set?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, geospatial

Okay, I have a reasonably complex query which checks to see if a point variable, containing a set of latitude+longitude coordinates (which I have substituted with `-41.000000` & `174.000000` for readability) is contained within a polygon, which is created from my table called `squares` (which contains 2.25m rows of coordinates representing the top left corner of a square, which I then extrapolate out by adding `0.5 / 60` to each coordinate to create a square). It checks to see if there's a match by using the MySQL `MBRContains` function. The only problem is, it isn't working at all, and I simply get this message:

`MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).`

Here's the query:

```
SELECT `square_id` FROM `squares` WHERE 

MBRContains(
    GeomFromText(
            CONCAT(
                    'POLYGON((',
                        `coord_lat`,' ',`coord_long`,',',
                        `coord_lat`,' ',(`coord_long` + (0.5 / 60)),',',
                        (`coord_lat` + (0.5 / 60)),' ',(`coord_long` + (0.5 / 60)),',',
                        (`coord_lat` + (0.5 / 60)),' ',`coord_long`,
                    '))'
                  )
               ),
   GeomFromText('POINT(-41.000000 174.000000)')
)
```

Any idea why this is? There definitely is a square that contains the coordinates within my point object, and I can't see any obvious errors in my SQL syntax. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide the lat/lng

Answer (score 0):

Two things going on here:

1. Vertices in WKT definitions are defined as (X,Y), unlike latitude/longitude, which is defined as "X,Y".  You are building up your WKT POLYGON and POINT strings using (lat lng), but should be using (lng lat).  Since you're consistent about it, this would work here, but might break in other situations.
2. The actual problem is the POLYGON you are creating is not closed.  MySQL quietly returns a null when GeomFromText is passed an invalid WKT string, so the MBRContains doesn't find any intersections.   To close the POLYGON, you need to add the start point to the end of the polygon string.  Try changing your SQL to this:

> ```
> SELECT `square_id` FROM `squares` WHERE
> MBRContains(
>   GeomFromText(
>         CONCAT(
>                 'POLYGON((',
>                     `coord_lat`,' ',`coord_long`,',',
>                     `coord_lat`,' ',(`coord_long` + (0.5 / 60)),',',
>                     (`coord_lat` + (0.5 / 60)),' ',(`coord_long` + (0.5 / 60)),',',
>                     (`coord_lat` + (0.5 / 60)),' ',`coord_long`,',',
>                     `coord_lat`,' ',`coord_long`
>                 '))'
>               )
>            ),
>   GeomFromText('POINT(-41.000000 174.000000)')
> )
> ```